# How to handle multiple elements loading into dom vue3 with vuecal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-cal

I'm using [Vue-cal](https://antoniandre.github.io/vue-cal/) in vue3, and sometimes frontend can load thousands of events in calendar and i don't know what type of optimization i can implement for this situations.

If calendar have >500 events, when they  are inserted into dom the page frezzes for some time.

the events come from a reactive state of pinia and go to the bind array vue-cal needs to display the events... but sometimes i need to insert 1000 at once

Do you guys know some strategy for improve this?

i've tried to chunk data but ended withou success

Comment: `i've tried to chunk data` how did you try this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.